# Ошибка в обработке нажатия на <select>

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, mobile-development

На сайте есть выбор размера товара, реализованный через `<select>`

```
<div class="item_sizes" >
    <label>Размер:
        <select name="sizes" id="sizes" class="item_sizes">
            <option value="">-- выбрать --</option>
            <option value="50 (L, 4)">50 (L, 4)</option>
            <option value="52 (XL, 5)">52 (XL, 5)</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

За обработку нажатия и передачу выбранного размера отвечает Javascript функция

```
$('.item_sizes').click(function(){
    var v=$(this).val();
    if(v){
        $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find('.button.cart')
            .attr('size',v);
    }
});
```

Выбор размера состоит минимум из двух кликов: 1 клик на `item_sizes` для раскрытия списка размеров. 2 клик на нужный размер (например `52 (XL, 5)` )

Если мы используем браузер на Windows (например Chrome), то  функция работает и размер передается.
Если мы используем  Android, Mac или IPhone, то сразу размер не передастся, а передастся только после повторного нажатия на `item_sizes` (можно нажать как на выпадающий список , так ни на слово `Размеры:`) Тогда функция срабатывает заново и размер передается.

Как переписать функцию, что бы при использовании любой системы выбранный размер сразу передавался без дополнительных кликов?

Comment: а почему вместо `click`не использовать `change` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, причина такого поведения кроется в отличающейся реализации выпадающих списков на мобильных платформах. Так клик по списку не является кликом по родительскому элементу, потому что список появляется отдельным элементом (по крайней мере на андроид так), поэтому лучше использовать, как Вам уже посоветовали, событие change

```
$('#sizes').change(function(){
    var v=$(this).val();
    if(v){/*...*/}
});
```